# How to use the output of a function and assign it to a variable in VB.net/visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Any help would be great as I am confused at the moment on how to do it.

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/function and also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e34641s.aspx

Comment: This is literally one of the easier things you can do in pretty much _any_ programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare a variable and set it to the value of the Function like this:

```
 Dim returnValue = SomeFunction()
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ways

```
Dim myStringValue As String

Function StringFunction() As String
    'Do something
    myStringValue = resultOfSomething
End Function
```

You should avoid populating variables from within a function though, so this would be preferred:

```
Function StringFunction() As String
    'Do something
    Return resultOfSomething
End Function

Dim myStringValue As String = StringFunction()
```